# How do I log the outputs of hidden Keras layer during training?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to store the float values in the outputs of a particular hidden layer during training. However, since the outputs are KerasTensor objects, I am unable to access them.

How do I access the float values in the tensors so I can store them for later use?

I am currently trying to do this using a custom Callback:

```py
class HidInps(Callback):
    def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        layer_out = self.model.get_layer("hidlyr").output
        print(layer_out)  # KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 3), dtype=tf.float32...
        print(keras.backend.get_value(layer_out))
```

However, since the KerasTensor object provides no .numpy() method, eval() or get_value() can not work and I get the appropriate error:

`AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the custom training loop in tensorflow to acheive this thing.
Lets say your model instance is refered by the variable `my_model`. You can create another `custom_model`  from it as follows:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Model

hidden_layer = self.model.get_layer("hidlyr")
custom_model = Model(inputs=my_model.inputs, outputs=[hidden_layer.output, my_model.output])
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    layer_op, predictions = custom_model(images)
print(layer_op)
```

For further details, refer https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_training_walkthrough#train_the_model

Answer (score 0):

```py
from tensorflow.keras import Model

hidden_layer = self.model.get_layer("hidlyr")
custom_model = Model(inputs=my_model.inputs, outputs=[hidden_layer.output, my_model.output])
with tf.GradientTape() as t:
    layer_op, predictions = custom_model(images)
print(layer_op)
```